# zsh inconsistent number of TABs for autocomplete menu

Tags: shell, zsh

I noticed the following behaviour in zsh:
Let's say I have 3 folders I want to `cd` into: `test1/ test2/ test3/`
If I press:

```
% cd t<TAB>
```

zsh autocompletes up to `test`, but does not show the autocomplete menu. It takes another `<TAB>` for it to show up. However if I put another folder in there:

```
% mkdir tx
% cd t<TAB>
```

I get:

```
% cd t
test1/  test2/  test3/  tx/
```

How can I configure it to be consistent (get the autocomplete menu after the first TAB) ? I tried setting the `menu_complete` option but that also fills in the first match, which is not what I like.

*Edit*: just tried in `bash`, and it doesn't seem to suffer from this problem

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a normal behavior, in the first case, "t" is not the maximal sequence which is equal within the names "test1", "test2", "test3": it's "test" thus it completes until you get "test", then you get the menu. In the second case, "t" is the maximal sequence thus zsh gives you the autocomplete menu.

If instead of getting all the remaining characters shared by possible matches you want to access the menu directly, you can use the zsh setopt menucomplete:

In either 'cd' attempt I write t and hit tab only once:

```
% ls
testA  testB  testC  tr 
% cd test
% setopt menucomplete
% cd t
testA/  testB/  testC/  tr/
% rmdir tr
% cd testA/
testA/  testB/  testC/
```

Comment: Is there an option which will expand the word on the command line to the longest common prefix *and* show the menu all in one <Tab> keystroke?

Comment: what @Peeja said (that's basically my question)

Comment: If you have only testA testB and testC, and you set the menucomplete option, then it will complete "t" to "testA" (and then testB and testC if you hit tab again). I don't know if there is a mechanism that would complete to "test" instead but what's the point? You will have to pick one of the three choices anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To always have a menu for the completion of the `cd` command, use:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*' menu yes select
```

The `select` key word is the key one, from the manual *If the value contains the string `select', menu selection will be started unconditionally*. Check the zsh manual for further ways to configure this call. Such as using

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:cd:*' menu yes select=4
```

that means force menu if there are at least 4 different matches. Notice there is also `select=long` and `select=long-list`.

Comment: unfortunately this still fills-in the first match automatically

Comment: FWIW, my understanding then is that your question's wording could be better, what you want is a 'list'. A 'menu' in Zsh will always fill in the values. Likely you'll need to use force-list(?).

Comment: yea sorry, I am very not familiar with the terminology, I just don't want to press two tabs when I could do just one, and I don't want the first match to be completed automatically. Just try my example in bash, you will see what I mean.